# Yannis's yinit font (gothic initials) and metapost

Tags: fonts, metapost

I am trying to produce EPS standalone files for all Gothic Initials from the Yannis'metafont sources recently reissued by Karl Berry for TL2014 (texmf-dist/fonts/source/public/gothic/).

I run mfplain on a Linux machine:

`% mfplain yinit.mf`

EPS files yinitas.65 ... yinitas.90 are produced with no error message, but

1. in letter A (yinit.65) the right leg is missing;
2. all bounding boxes are wrong (a lot too deep);
3. the foreground color is grey instead of black…

For instance, trying to preview any letter, say D, with gv:

`% gv yinit.68&`

shows the D letter which looks correct except for the bounding box, but issues the following ghostscript error:

> Last OS error: Resource temporarily unavailable Current file position
>   is 42886 Error: /undefined in cmr10 Operand stack:    (2l) Execution
>   stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--
>   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:    --dict:GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit code
>   1 1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)-- Current
>   allocation mode is local Current file position is 42886 Error:
>   /undefined in cmr10GPL Ghostscript 9.06: Unrecoverable error, exit
>   code 1
>
> Operand stack:    (2l) Execution stack:    %interp_exit   .runexec2
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
>   false   1   %stopped_push   1910   1   3   %oparray_pop   1909   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   1893   1   3   %oparray_pop   1787   1   3
>   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2
>   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval-- Dictionary stack:
>   --dict:1169/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--

On the other hand, I have been able to reproduce the font table yinit.pdf with metafont, gftopk and nfssfont, this table is correct. Am I missing something or is there a bug in metapost?

Thanks in advance for any hint.

Best wishes,

Comment: Isn't it just because it is referring to the CM fonts and it is not embedding it into the generated EPS. You get the same issue with normal metafont files, where you just use a `prolouges` specification to tell metapost to embed or not. There is more in the metapost manual.

Comment: I highly recommend you to get the book ‘‘Fontes et codages’’ of the same Yannis Haralambous and particularly the Appendix F, section 4 (dedicated to MetaType1), which explains why it is sometimes very tricky to apply MetaPost on Metafont files without care. Some parts of the glyphs may then not appear at all.

Comment: I have tried a script mf2pt1 by Scott Pakin:
`mf2pt1 yinit.mf`.
A resulting yinit.pfb seems relatively good,
in spite of many 'Internal Error' messages.

`t1testpage yinit.pfb -o yinit.ps`
`ps2pdf yinit.ps yinit.pdf`

Comment: Thanks Akira, indeed the mf2pt1.pl script does a better job than mfplain: bounding boxes are correct and the foreground color is black. The only remaining glitch is the missing right leg of letter A.

Comment: @Daniel - Here all characters seem perfect:
`MetaPost 1.999, revision 2056`.

Comment: @Akira - Good news! I run MetaPost 1.902 (TeX Live 2014), I'll wait for TL2015 to try again. Thanks.